# vue 2 global compoenent called inside another won't render

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I am adding tinymce to my Laravel 5.4 project. I have made it into a global component. This works fine. Does what it's supposed to and everything is great. Now, when following along to Laracasts latest "build a forum with TDD" series.. I got to thinking I can just add in that component to the reply component and use it there too! Yeah.. no. I'm a vue nub, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Can anyone help?  I even decided to call the global as a child component too.. no joy there either.

Vue debugging tools on chrome says it's there... but the editor won't render. So I'm a bit confused. I've tried adding `<slot>`  to various places too, that made no change. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks all!

Code below-

app.js:

```
Vue.component('flash', require('./components/Flash.vue'));
Vue.component('reply', require('./components/Reply.vue'));
Vue.component('tinymce-editor',require('./components/Tinymce.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Tinymce.vue:

```
<template>
    <textarea name="body" class="form-control" id="tinymce" v-text="body" rows="5"></textarea>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'tinymce-editor',
        props: {
            body: {
                default: 'Something to say, have you?'
            }
        },

        mounted: function() {
            const self = this;
            tinymce.init({
                menubar: false,
                path_absolute: "/",
                selector: "#tinymce",
                entity_encoding: "raw",
                toolbar_items_size: "small",
                style_formats: [
                    {"title": "Bold", "icon": "bold", "format": "bold"},
                    {"title": "Italic", "icon": "italic", "format": "italic"},
                    {"title": "Underline", "icon": "underline", "format": "underline"},
                    {"title": "Strikethrough", "icon": "strikethrough", "format": "strikethrough"},
                    {"title": "Superscript", "icon": "superscript", "format": "superscript"},
                    {"title": "Subscript", "icon": "subscript", "format": "subscript"},
                    {"title": "Code", "icon": "code", "format": "code"}
                ],
                plugins: 'advlist anchor autolink autoresize code colorpicker hr image link lists preview searchreplace spellchecker textcolor wordcount',
                block_formats: "Paragraph=p;Heading 1=h1;Heading 2=h2;Heading 3=h3;Heading 4=h4;Heading 5=h5;Heading 6=h6;",
                toolbar1: "undo redo | formatselect | bullist numlist | link unlink | uploadimg image",
                toolbar2: "styleselect fontsizeselect | forecolor | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | removeformat",
                init_instance_callback: function(editor) {

                    // init tinymce
                    editor.on('init', function () {
                        tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(self.value);
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        update: function(newVal, oldVal) {
            // set val and trigger event
            $(this.el).val(newVal).trigger('keyup');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Reply.vue:

```
<script>
    import Favorite from './Favorite.vue';
    import Tinymce from './Tinymce.vue';
    export default {
        name: 'Reply',
        props: ['attributes'],

        components: {
            'favorite': Favorite,
            'tinymce-editor': Tinymce
        },

        data() {
            return {
                editing: false,
                body: this.attributes.body
            };
        },

        methods: {
            update() {
                axios.patch('/replies/' + this.attributes.id, {
                    body: this.body
                });

                this.editing = false;

                flash('Updated!');
            },

            destroy() {
                axios.delete('/replies/' + this.attributes.id);

                $(this.$el).fadeOut(300, () => {
                    flash('Your reply has been deleted.');
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

reply.blade.php:

```
<reply :attributes="{{ $reply }}" inline-template v-cloak>
    <div id="reply-{{$reply->id}}" class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="level">
                <h5 class="flex">
                    <a href="{{ route('profile',$reply->owner->name) }}">
                        {{ $reply->owner->name }}
                    </a> said {{ $reply->created_at->diffForHumans() }}...
                </h5>

                <favorite :reply="{{$reply}}"></favorite>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div v-if="editing">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <tinymce-editor body="{{ $reply->body }}"></tinymce-editor>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" @click="update">Update</button>
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-link" @click="editing = false">Cancel</button>
            </div>

            <div v-else v-html="body"></div>
        </div>
        @can('update', $reply)
            <div class="panel-footer level">
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success mr-1" @click="editing = true">Edit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger mr-1" @click="destroy">Delete</button>
            </div>
        @endcan
    </div>
</reply>
```

Comment: Not absolutely sure but I think that you should name the component TinymceEditor in order to render it as <tinymce-editor> That means:
`Vue.component('TinymceEditor',require('./components/Tinymce.vue'));`

Comment: Since the TinymceEditor component is registered at the global level, you don't need to import it again in the Reply.vue component. Try removing the import statement and remove the entry from the `components` property in Reply.vue

Comment: Thanks for the tips, neither helped though. It's still not rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. There were actually two problems here. The IDs on the editors were not unique. So that is why the child editor did not render. Once I solved that, I had the issue of the child not updating the parent. So I had to fix that as well. Updated code below for anyone else who might want it. This might not be "best practice" code, but it works. I'm very much open to improvements! Thanks all!

Reply.vue:

```
<script>
    import Favorite from './Favorite.vue';

    export default {
        name: 'Reply',
        props: ['attributes'],

        components: {
            'favorite': Favorite,
        },

        data() {
            return {
                editing: false,
                body: this.attributes.body
            };
        },

        methods: {
            updateBody(newContent) {
                this.body = newContent;
            },

            update() {
                axios.patch('/replies/' + this.attributes.id, {
                    body: this.body
                });

                this.editing = false;

                flash('Updated!');
            },

            destroy() {
                axios.delete('/replies/' + this.attributes.id);

                $(this.$el).fadeOut(300, () => {
                    flash('Your reply has been deleted.');
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Tinymce.vue:

```
<template>
    <textarea :id="id" name="body" class="form-control" rows="5" >{{ body }}</textarea>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'tinymce-editor',
        props: {
            body: {
                default: 'Something to say, have you?'
            }
        },

        data(){
            return {
                id: 'tinymce-'+Date.now(),
            }
        },

        mounted: function() {
            const self = this;
            tinymce.init({
                menubar: false,
                path_absolute: "/",
                selector: '#'+self.id,
                entity_encoding: "raw",
                toolbar_items_size: "small",
                style_formats: [
                    {"title": "Bold", "icon": "bold", "format": "bold"},
                    {"title": "Italic", "icon": "italic", "format": "italic"},
                    {"title": "Underline", "icon": "underline", "format": "underline"},
                    {"title": "Strikethrough", "icon": "strikethrough", "format": "strikethrough"},
                    {"title": "Superscript", "icon": "superscript", "format": "superscript"},
                    {"title": "Subscript", "icon": "subscript", "format": "subscript"},
                    {"title": "Code", "icon": "code", "format": "code"}
                ],
                plugins: 'advlist anchor autolink autoresize code colorpicker hr image link lists preview searchreplace spellchecker textcolor wordcount',
                block_formats: "Paragraph=p;Heading 1=h1;Heading 2=h2;Heading 3=h3;Heading 4=h4;Heading 5=h5;Heading 6=h6;",
                toolbar1: "undo redo | formatselect | bullist numlist | link unlink | uploadimg image",
                toolbar2: "styleselect fontsizeselect | forecolor | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | removeformat",
                init_instance_callback: function(editor) {

                    // init tinymce
                    editor.on('init', function () {
                        tinymce.editors[self.id].setContent(self.body);
                    });

                    editor.on('keyup', function() {
                        const newContent = tinymce.editors[self.id].getContent();

                        // Fire an event to let its parent know
                        self.$emit('content-updated', newContent);
                    });
                }
            });
        },

        update: function() {
            const self = this;

            if (self.body) {
                tinymce.editors[self.id].setContent(self.body);
            }
        },

        beforeDestroy: function(){
            tinymce.remove(this.id)
        }
    }
</script>
```

reply.blade.php:

```
<reply :attributes="{{ $reply }}" inline-template v-cloak>
    <div id="reply-{{$reply->id}}" class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="level">
                <h5 class="flex">
                    <a href="{{ route('profile',$reply->owner->name) }}">
                        {{ $reply->owner->name }}
                    </a> said {{ $reply->created_at->diffForHumans() }}...
                </h5>

                <favorite :reply="{{$reply}}"></favorite>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div v-if="editing">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <tinymce-editor v-model="body" body="{{ $reply->body }}" v-on:content-updated="updateBody"></tinymce-editor>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" @click="update">Update</button>
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-link" @click="editing = false">Cancel</button>
            </div>

            <div v-else v-html="body"></div>
        </div>
        @can('update', $reply)
            <div class="panel-footer level">
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success mr-1" @click="editing = true">Edit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger mr-1" @click="destroy">Delete</button>
            </div>
        @endcan
    </div>
</reply>
```